# How to order a list in ascending order by it's name c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have this function that takes a list and needs to order it in ascending order by the name, I've taken the query from a previous function, but now Im stuck on what I have to change to make it work beacuse I don't know Linq, this is the function:

```
private void OrderList(List<string> ListaFiles)
{
   List<string> list = ((IEnumerable<string>)Directory.GetFiles(Directories, "*.sql", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)).Select(f =>
    {
      string[] strArray = Path.GetFileName(f).Split('_');
      int result;
      if (strArray.Length < 1 || !int.TryParse(strArray[0], out result))
          result = -1;
      var data = new
      {
        File = f,
        Version = result
      };
      return data;
      }).Where(f => f.Version > -1).OrderBy(f => f.Version).Select(f => f.File).ToList<string>();
}
```

I only want to select from the list so the `((IEnumerable<string>)Directory.GetFiles(Directories, "*.sql", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))` isn't necessary.

> I want to order the list that I pass to the function as a parameter, and the files are named like this: 1_ORCA_3-9_56.sql the first number represents the execution order of the files, so I need to sort the files by that name ascending
>
> I will actually be passing a struct that contains 3 lists that need to be sorted
>
> The files name are full path

Comment: I'm a little confused. which list do you want to sort and by what "Name"?

Comment: @RenéVogt  I want to order the list that I pass to the function as a parameter, and the files are named like this: 1_ORCA_3-9_56.sql the first number represents the execution order of the files, so I need to sort the files by that name ascending

Comment: There is `OrderBy()` extension method. Have you tried it?

Comment: I tried to pretty-print your code, because now it is sticking out to the right of the page, and there are many levels of quotes, but I gave up. Could you please improve the format? Then it might be easier for me to grasp your problem and find a solution

Comment: @Roland sure I will try to make it look nicer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there may be files in the list that do not have the desired name format, you should at first filter them out using `Where()`.
Then you need to parse the first part of the string to an `int` and use `OrderBy()` to sort the list by that `int`:

```
var orderedAndFilteredFileList = ListaFiles
        .Where(s => Regex.IsMatch(Path.GetFileName(s), @"^\d+_"))
        .OrderBy(s => Convert.ToInt32(Path.GetFileName(s).Split('_')[0])).ToList();
```

This uses a regular expression to check if the file name has the desired format and filters out all other files. Then orders the sequence by getting the file name from the full path (using `Path.GetFileName()`), splits that name at the `_` and parses the first part to an `int` that is finally used as sorting criteria.

The final `ToList()` call turns the `IEnumerable<string>` returned by `OrderBy()` into a `List<string>` again.

Comment: will I still be getting the full file path in the end?

Comment: @LikeIfYouCaredAboutMyName Yes, the `int` is only used as sorting criteria. The result of `OrderBy` is an `IEnumerable<string>` containing the original elements, but ordered by that `int`. You may wish to call `.ToList()` on that to make it a `List<string>` again.

Comment: @LikeIfYouCaredAboutMyName updated my answer with error handling

Comment: so the first thing to do is the last thing you changed in the question and the last is the first you posted?

Comment: @LikeIfYouCaredAboutMyName not really, there is no order or combination of the snippets, all three examples stand for themselves. I suggest to take the last one as it filters out invalid files.

Comment: yup I took the last one, I really like your aproach on that with filtering out the invalid files. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order the inputted list by the first number of the file name you will need to split the strings then order i.e.

```
private List<string> OrderList(List<string> ListaFiles)
{
     return ListaFiles.Select(f => Convert.ToInt32(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f.Split('_').First())))
                      .OrderBy(f => f);
                      .ToList();
}
```

Although this code will throw an exception if the strings are empty, the split returns nothing or the first string after the split is not in an integer format.

As per your comments on other answers you want the full paths at the end so you need to remove the select statement so your method becomes the following:

```
private List<string> OrderList(List<string> ListaFiles)
{
     return ListaFiles.OrderBy(f => Convert.ToInt32(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f.Split('_').First())))
                      .ToList();
}
```

Comment: the files are full path, forgot to mention that

Comment: that will still throw exceptions?

Comment: @LikeIfYouCaredAboutMyName All of the answers will throw exceptions if the input is not in the expected format

Answer (score 0):

You could do this.

```
ListaFiles.OrderBy(x=>
{
     var version = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x).Split('_')[0];
     return int.Parse(version);
});
```

Comment: In the end that will still give the the list with the full path?

Comment: Yes, you just need file names?

Comment: I need the full file path

Comment: Then this query is correct, it returns full file path.